# Anchor tag image joomla

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla2.5, virtuemart

How can I use an image button instead of the text in the following code

```
JHTML::link ($product->link, JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DETAILS'), array('title' => $product->product_name, 'class' => 'product-details'))
```

in HTML it is rendering as `<a href="blah blah">Product details`

How to use the image instead of Product details in HREF tag in above php code

```
JHTML::link ($product->link, JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DETAILS'), array('title' => $product->product_name, 'class' => 'product-details'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$product` is a PHP object, and JHTML is used by joomla! framework to output links

Actually your code:

```
JHTML::link ($product->link, JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DETAILS'), array('title' => $product->product_name, 'class' => 'product-details'))
```

is equal to plain HTML

```
<a href="<?php echo $product->link; ?>" title="<?php echo $product->product_name ?>" class="product-details"> <?php JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DETAILS');?></a>
```

JText is used to output words and phrases based in a language INI file based in language/LANGUAGE_ID/folder. For english language and virtuemart component your string is located in /language/en-GB/en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini

in order to use an image link try

```
<a href="<?php echo $product->link; ?>" title="<?php echo $product->product_name ?>" class="product-details"> <img=src="myimage.png" /></a>
```